# c# chart with multiple series

Tags: c#, charts, series

I have a code for making chart with multiple series that have the same x value like this    :

```
Series s = new Series("First");
s.Points.AddXY("a", 10);
s.Points.AddXY("b", 10);
s.Points.AddXY("c", 10);
chart1.Series.Add(s);
s = new Series("Second");
s.Points.AddXY("c", 30);
chart1.Series.Add(s);
```

but unfortunately when I add second series to my chart the info of columns "c" goes for columns "a"
there is no info for columns "a" and "b" in second series
 how can I solve this problem
Thank u all for helping me

Answer (score 2):

You use the `Series s` object two times. Try this

```
   Series s = new Series("First");
   s.Points.AddXY("a", 10);
   s.Points.AddXY("b", 10);
   s.Points.AddXY("c", 10);
   chart1.Series.Add(s);
   Series s2 = new Series("Second");
   s2.Points.AddXY("c", 30);
   chart1.Series.Add(s2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this too but the problem still the same of before

Comment: Can you explain clearly the output you have and the output u want?

Comment: I have Two series of info to build a chart. i the second series there is no y value for some x value. when I build my chart all of second series y value go to right in incorrect place.

Answer (score 2):

It's been solved by:

```
chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
```